# how do I downgrade google chrome?

Tags: apt, google-chrome, synaptic, aptitude, downgrade

Presumably after an update, google chrome has very serious problems with page rendering. I want to downgrade it. (Switching to `vmlinuz.old` and `initrd.img.old` did not help).

```
$ apt-cache policy google-chrome-stable
google-chrome-stable:
  Installed: 35.0.1916.153-1
  Candidate: 35.0.1916.153-1
  Version table:
 *** 35.0.1916.153-1 0
        500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

on a computer where google chrome works ok:

```
$ apt-cache policy google-chrome-stable
google-chrome-stable:
  Installed: 34.0.1847.132-1
  Candidate: 35.0.1916.153-1
  Version table:
     35.0.1916.153-1 0
        500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 34.0.1847.132-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

(If I had the .deb on the 2nd computer, everything would be easier. But there's no .deb. And no old .deb's on the google site.)

So I try:

```
$ sudo aptitude install google-chrome-stable=34.0.1847.132-1
Unable to find a version "34.0.1847.132-1" for the package "google-chrome-stable"
Unable to find a version "34.0.1847.132-1" for the package "google-chrome-stable"
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

You see, it does not work. The Synaptic manager also shows no version that I could set.

***So, how do I downgrade google-chrome-stable?***

Probably someone knows an archive of old google-chrome .deb's?

Comment: it seems like the previous version isn't available in the repository. So try to download the deb file of previous version and install it through `dpkg -i` command.

Comment: "Switching to vmlinuz.old and initrd.img.old did not help" - why would it have? That's like putting on yesterday's pants because the car won't start this morning.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know where to download that .deb from.

Comment: @Oli which component provides the low-level functionality for graphical output then? The problem with chrome is that I see rectangles that do not refresh when I open/re-load/scroll/resize the window.

Answer (score 9):

An archive of old google chrome versions may be found at:

http://mirror.pcbeta.com/google/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/

Unfortunately, google-chrome will tell you that the stuff in `~/.config/google-chrome` is from a newer version. I renamed this directory to `google-chrome_newer` hoping to return to it when the problem with chrome is fixed.

EDIT There's no problem with that stuff from newer version, just press "ok". And I am afraid the chrome will never be fixed.

EDIT2

mirror.pcbeta.com does not work now. As usual, you may use https://archive.org/web/ .

The direct link to the page of interest is:
https://web.archive.org/web/20160322044606/http://mirror.pcbeta.com/google/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/

If you have problems connecting to web.archive.org, e.g. "DNS address could not be found", try to use the TOR Browser (probably with its "New TOR circuit for this site" feature, Ctrl+Shift+L).

Answer (score 7):

**On your 2nd computer**

1. Your deb file is in:

   ```
   /var/cache/apt/archives
   ```
2. If not, install it again via:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable=34.0.1847.132-1
   ```
3. After that upgrade via:

   ```
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

**On your 1st computer:**

1. Transfer the file and install via:

   ```
   dpkg -i your.deb
   ```
2. And set the package `google-chrome-stable` on hold via

   ```
   sudo apt-mark hold google-chrome-stable
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override newer version with older version, follow below steps-

First, go to Ubuntu Updates and pick the full version string of the version you want to install. Just copy and paste the version string, do not download any packages from this 3rd party website!

Now download the older version directly from Google's Download Servers:

```
$ VERSION_STRING="85.0.4183.121-1" # Replace this value with the one you copied earlier
$ wget "https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_${VERSION_STRING}_amd64.deb"
$ sudo dpkg -i "google-chrome-stable_${VERSION_STRING}_amd64.deb"
$ rm -i "google-chrome-stable_${VERSION_STRING}_amd64.deb"
```